# how to make curved widget with custom cliper in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make this widget this is my final goal

[image]

I tried to follow some tutorials to make curved app bars but i couldn't get to the same result as i want.
is there anyway to convert svg curve to this curve clipper?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com) to make any custom shape you want, you can also follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnKgtKxRLX4)